# phonegap get photo file's original imageURI

Tags: iphone, cordova

phonegap's camera API has this iphone quirk noted:

When destinationType.FILE_URI is used, photos are saved in the application's temporary directory.

details [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

and when I load the photo from album, I get imageURI like this

file://localhost/var/folders/sV/sVG0cyUrFvKs6+6I16IO+U+++TI/-Tmp-/photo_007.jpg

and every time I get a different URI for the same photo. Is it possible to get the URI of the original photo file instead of the temporary copy? I need to have the image URI and display multiple photos on the same screen.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not possible on iOS as the photos are stored in an area that is not accessible via URL. We need to copy the image to the application specific temp directory so it will be readable by your app.

Comment: Thank you Simon for your reply. I guess with native iOS app, it's just reading the file and drawing the pixels directly on the screen. Can phonegap just provides the original file path anyway (as well as the copy in the temp directory) so that my application can have a consistent file reference for a specific photo, and my application can make a temp copy myself.

Imagine this scenario, I pick a photo, show it on my page. I save the page. Next time I open my app, the same photo is already there. If I have the original photo file path, I could just do a copy to temp dir myself to achieve that.

Comment: At least getting the original file name as a parameter to the callback function will help to check it the same image is already processed or not.